# Can anyone explain why is my floodfill function not working in python openCV2

Tags: python, opencv

[image]

I am trying to flood fill the border of the black rectangular border and innermost filled black circle in this image with white color .

I googled and found that python has  cv2.floodFill().
According to the documentation , it requires the following parameter:

```
 cv2.floodFill(image, mask, seedPoint, newVal[, loDiff[, upDiff[, flags]]])
```

Here image is the input image which I want to edit . My image name is testpoint.png

For seed point , I am selecting (0,0) to first flood fill the outer black ring.

Since I want to flood fill the black outer rectangular border with white color , i chose the value for newVal (255,255,255)

I set the lodiff and updiff value to 20 and flags = 4 (for 4 connected pixel floodfill ) .

For mask parameter , i set it to none

```
cv2.floodFill(test_image,None,(0,0), (255, 255 ,255), 20, 20, 4)
```

This however dose not seem to work. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What do you get? Please post your code.

Comment: The image you provided has some white space around your outer black rectangle, is that the same for the image, you're actually using? Then, the point `(0, 0)` is no proper seed point. You need to find a proper point inside that rectangle. For the attached image, that could be `(60, 60)` for example. Using that seed point on the given image, the black rectangle is correctly floodfilled.

Answer (score 0):

Try this floodfill code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('/home/stephen/Desktop/uLUC6.png')
# Flood from (0,0) - gray
floodfill_color = 123,123,123
seed_point = 0,0
cv2.floodFill(img, None, seed_point, floodfill_color)
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

You don't need to include the other parameters.
[image: output]